# Designing a PostgreSQL database for high-volume updates

Tags: postgresql, database-design, configuration, architecture

I am designing a database for a system that has to handle lots of writes operations (99%+ are updates, sometimes inserts) but at all times it has to provide fast reads. At the moment selects take a lot of time to complete.

There are around 20 processes (each on its own server) that communicate with the database server at the same time. Each process has to update rows and in order to avoid multiple processes updating the same row in parallel, we use a particular column `queued` which indicates if a row has already been queued by one process. In more detail:

1. A process requests data from the database with a query like this:

   ```
   WITH selected AS
       (SELECT username FROM profiles
           WHERE queued = false FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED LIMIT %(n)s)
   UPDATE profiles
       SET
           queued = true
       WHERE username IN (SELECT username FROM selected)
   RETURNING username;
   ```
2. After it has finishing updating each profile we run the following query

   ```
   INSERT INTO profiles (
       ...
   ) values (
       ...
   )
   ON CONFLICT (username) DO UPDATE
       SET
           ...
   ;
   ```

Presently we have around 1.7-1.9M updates per day. As mentioned, selects are really slow when all these processes are updating rows. The database server has 4 cores and 25GB of RAM and runs PostgreSQL 9.6 with the following parameters:

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 2560MB
effective_cache_size = 7680MB
maintenance_work_mem = 640MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 13107kB
min_wal_size = 2GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
```

With all these updates I guess I'll have to increase the autovacuum frequency, is that right? I am ok penalizing a bit the updates if in turn that guarantees fast reads.

Comment: For tables with a high UPDATE count, it is usually also a good idea to lower `fillfactor` (e.g. to 60 or 70)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Interesting, I didn't know about that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This is a rather small machine for what you are asking it to do. Somewhat more importantly what disks are you using?

Comment: @DaveCramer Good question. I have a single SSD that can be written at ~12MB/s. Postgres' checkpointer process writes about 2.55MB/s, while the writer process is at 0.9 MB/s. Then there are all the connections and in total I come very close to the limit. I definitely should improve the read/write performance. I don't think having more than one disk is going to improve things, or will it?

Comment: What is the nature of the slow selects?  Single row selects on a primary key?  Or is it the selects that are part of the update which are slow?

Comment: @jjanes The selects that are part of the update are a bit slow but that's not a problem. The important selects are the one coming from the application that it's connected to this database, and they mainly are searches over the `profiles` table. It's most of the time full-text searches, and some filtering based on a few other columns. In order to support full-text search and these filters I have lots of indices. They make the updates a little slower but are absolutely needed.

Comment: It would really help to see a specific query, with an `explain (analyze, buffers)`.  Pick the worst one.  Or the simplest one which is noticeably bad.  Also, run it twice in a row and see if the second run as much faster.  Otherwise all we can do is give generic advice like "buy better hardware" or "vacuum more aggressively".  Also, if you stop doing updates, do the selects stop being slow?  What if you set up streaming hot standby and run the queries there?

Comment: @jjanes Thank you for being very helpful! I think I solved most of my problems. In the end I did the following:
1) setup hot standby replica (for backup only, since queries there take forever)  
2) more aggressive vacuum  
3) **materialized views**: this is a godsend. This way the processes can write to their tables and the application can read on the materialized views, which are i) smaller tables and ii) never locked